# How do I get the file name that triggered a Azure Function Blob Trigger

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-triggers

I have a Azure function with a blob trigger in Python that scans the content of of PDF files that get added to a container, how do I get the file name of the file that triggered the trigger e.g. "bank_data.pdf"?

```
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
   blob = {myblob.name}
```

I get this error when trying to get the name through the InputStream:

```
Result: Failure Exception: FunctionLoadError: cannot load the pdf_blob_trigger_test function: the following parameters are declared in Python but not in function.json: {'name'} Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 371, in _handle__function_load_request self._functions.add_function( File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/functions.py", line 353, in add_function input_types, output_types = self.validate_function_params(params, File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/functions.py", line 137, in validate_function_params raise FunctionLoadError(
```

function.json

```
{
"scriptFile": "__init__.py",
"bindings": [
    {
        "name": "myblob",
        "type": "blobTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "path": "data-upload-pdf-test/{name}.pdf",
        "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
        "containerName": "data-upload-pdf-test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Solution to my problem is in the comments of the accepted answer

Comment: How is your function.json file looks like

Comment: Yes, the Azure Input Stream just returns a huge header, not the name of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly, go to Function App, I have used Logs section to find which file is triggered my Azure Blob Trigger by using below KQL query:

```
traces 
| where message contains "Python blob trigger"
```

[image]

In Storage Account:

[image]

***init*.py**

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

[image]

So, you can able to log the details of file name in Logs section of function app.
So, used  `f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"` to print file name which triggered.

Comment: How would i save the name to a variable instead of logging? As the file name will be needed later in the script

Comment: You can save some variable= myblob.name as a variable, Here myblob is the blob and myblob.name is the name of the blob.

Comment: I get an error when i do that unfortunately.  If you see my edited question

Comment: remove paranthesis {}, Another thing you can directly use myblob.name as a variable right? why to assign it to another variable?

Comment: it seems using myblob.name as a variable works!! But saving it to a variable doesnt, weird. But thanks for the help!